What is the exact ground state energy of the 1D finite XY model in open boundary condition?
From what I understand, the XY model is exactly mapped to free fermions tight-binding approximation. I follow this lecture notes to find the formula for ground state of the model to be
$$
k = \frac{2\pi n}{N}, -N/2 \le n \le N/2-1, E_0 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_k \frac{1}{2}|\cos(k)|
$$
I set $N=100$ and calculate this on Python to get E=-0.31820515953773953
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
N = 100
klist = (np.arange(N)-N/2)/N
E = -sum(np.abs(np.cos((np.pi*2*klist))))/2/N

At the same time I compare this with the "exact" energy from Tensors.net that they use to compare with their DMRG, and get E2 = -0.316505945777101
H = np.diag(np.ones(N-1),k=1) + np.diag(np.ones(N-1),k=-1)
D = LA.eigvalsh(H)
E2 = sum(D[D < 0])/2/N

This is basically a matrix with no diagonal elements, but off-diagonal elements. I find the discrepancy at 2nd number of significant to be too big for two results that both claim to be exact. So I have 2 questions, perhaps:

What's the logic behind this formula from Tensors.net?

I believe I have made a misunderstanding somewhere as to why they're so different?


Can you guys show me what went wrong? Thank you!

What does OBC mean?

I mean open boundary condition. Sorry.

For larger values of $N$, do they converge to a singular value?

Yes, they converge to $1/\pi$, the thermodynamic limit.

Okay, so then one is probably a better approximation than the other for lower resolution. Both numerical schemes have their own accuracies (truncation errors), so the difference is likely just due to that.

But my question is like, is there a formula for exactly the finite size system?

In the XY model with open BC the quasi momenta are not uniformly spaced. So the first formula is only an approximation. Tensor net presumably simulates the GS with a tensor network and if number of parameters is sufficiently large should give a good approximation. Anyway if I'm not mistaken here you're actually considering the quantum Ising model at $h=1$ which is a quantum critical point (and the convergence of tensor network energies should be only polynomial)

I think I may have written somewhere the actual form of the GS energy for OBC (if that's what you're interested in), but most likely the quasi momenta are roots of transcendental equations.

Yes, it'd be great if you can show me the formula! Thank you! But furthermore, I think the formula by Tensors.net wasn't made by TN methods; it's somehow a formula for the "exact" solution they used to compare with TN. That's why I have questions as to how that formula works...

Juan, if you want to notify a user, use @username in your comment. Otherwise they won't be notified in general if you respond.

You are considering isotropic XY model with open boundary conditions, whose Hamiltonian in terms of $1/2$ spin operators is
$$
\hat{H} = -\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\left(\hat{S}^x_j\hat{S}^x_{j+1} + \hat{S}^y_j\hat{S}^y_{j+1} \right)
$$
After the Jordan-Wigner transformation, this Hamiltonian is written in terms of the fermion creation and annihilation operators:
$$
\hat{H} = -\frac12\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\left(\hat{c}^\dagger_j\hat{c}^-_{j+1} + \hat{c}^\dagger_{j+1}\hat{c}^-_j \right) = \sum_{j,j\ '=1}^N T_{j,j\ '}\hat{c}^\dagger_{j}\hat{c}^-_{j\ '}
$$
where $T_{j,j\ '} = -\frac12$ if $j\ ' = j\pm1$ and $T_{j,j\ '} = 0$ else. Since this is a quadratic fermionic Hamiltonian without anomalous terms, it diagonalizes as follows:
$$
\hat{H} = \sum_k \varepsilon_k\hat{a}^\dagger_k\hat{a}_k^-,
$$
where $\hat{a}_k^- = \sum_{j=1}^N u_{j,k}\hat{c}_j^-$ and $\varepsilon_k$ and $u_{j,k}$ are the eigenvalues ​​and eigenvectors of the matrix $T$:
$$
\sum_{j\ ' = 1}^N T_{j,j\ '}u_{j\ ',k} = \varepsilon_k u_{j,k}
$$
In this particular problem it is known and can be easily verified that
$$
k = \frac{\pi l}{N+1}, \quad l = 1,\ldots,N
$$
and
$$
\varepsilon_k = -\cos(k),\qquad u_{j,k} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{N+1}}\sin{kj},\quad j=1,\ldots,N
$$
Now the ground energy of the free-fermions system is equal to
$$
E_0 = \sum_{k}\varepsilon_k\theta(-\varepsilon_k) = [\mbox{for even N}] = -\sum_{l=1}^{N/2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi l}{N+1}\right) =
$$
$$
= -\cos\left(\frac{\pi(N+2)}{4(N+1)}\right)\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi N}{4(N+1)}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2(N+1)}\right)}
$$
Substituting $N=100$ into the last formula and dividing by $N=100$ yields exactly the same number $E2 = -0.316505945777101$ for the ground state energy per spin.
On the difference between the numbers $E2$ and $E=-0.31820515953773953$. The latter is obtained in the case of periodic boundary conditions. If periodic boundary conditions are assumed, the Hamiltonian in the very first formula of this answer contains an additional term relating spins with numbers $1$ and $N$.
